# How to regrid the resolution of data with netcdf format in R

Tags: r, datagrid, spatial, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file named "precip.mon.mean.nc" downloaded from https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.cmap.html. It is a monthly mean precipitation dataset and the resolution is 2.5x2.5.

I wonder how I can regrid the precipitation data into 1x1 and 3x3 resolution respectively using interpolation method such as Kriging or inverse distance weighted (IDW). Thanks for the help.

```
require(ncdf4)

Precipitation = nc_open(filename = "precip.mon.mean.nc")
Pre=ncvar_get(Precipitation,varid = "precip")
Pre[Pre=-9.96920996838687e+36]=NA
lon=ncvar_get(Precipitation,varid = "lon")
aa=which(lon==181.25)
lon[aa:length(lon)]=lon[aa:length(lon)]-360
lat=ncvar_get(Precipitation,varid = "lat")
Date=ncvar_get(Precipitation,varid = "time")
nc_close(Precipitation)
Time=as.Date(Date/24,origin="1800-01-01")
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006045/obtain-function-from-akimainterp-matrix/43064436#43064436
You can also directly use `raster::aggregate` and `raster::disaggregate`

Comment: @StatnMap Thank you so much for your reply, but I am still a bit confused, I wonder if you could give me an example using the data in my post? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For general interpolation solutions using R, [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152308/how-to-change-the-resolution-or-regrid-data-in-r).

In addition, I haven't used it myself, [but the package idpw seems to have an option for inverse distance weighting](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ipdw/vignettes/ipdw2.html).In addition [this post](https://rpubs.com/Dr_Gurpreet/interpolation_idw_R) and [this page](https://rspatial.org/raster/analysis/4-interpolation.html) might help.

However, if you a very simple one liner, you can can do inverse distance weighting remapping of netcdf files by simply calling CDO with a system command. The option you need is `remapdis`, if the file is global you can simply specify the resolution using the regular grid specifier, for example with a 1x1 degree grid:

```
cdo remapdist,r360x180 precip.mon.mean.nc regridded.nc
```

[as I say, you can call this from R using the system function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516525/running-linux-commands-from-r/25516570).  For further information on regridding methods and potential pitfalls see my [online youtube video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79o6DXr_3zM).